# Finding my own BSD Name in kext for IOBlockStorageDevice

Tags: kernel, iokit, darwin, kernel-extension

I think this should be something really easy, but it is evading me at the moment. Most 
examples deal with "if you have a BSD name /dev/disk, how can you find the device", whereas I have just registered my device, and want to find the BSD Name it was give. Ie, /dev/disk2.

I make a standard

```
class net_lundman_zfs_zvol : public IOService
class net_lundman_zfs_zvol_device : public IOBlockStorageDevice
```

which creates a nub for a new device;

```
bool net_lundman_zfs_zvol::createBlockStorageDevice (zvol_state_t *zv)
{
    net_lundman_zfs_zvol_device *nub = NULL;
    bool            result = false;
    nub = new net_lundman_zfs_zvol_device;
    if (nub == NULL)        goto bail;
    if (nub->init(zv) == false)        goto bail;
    if (nub->attach(this) == false)        goto bail;
    nub->registerService();
}
```

Now, I'd like to find out the BSDName my new nub was given. Does not matter to me if it
if in net_lundman_zfs_zvol or net_lundman_zfs_zvol_device.

I thought I could just call

```
 getProperty(kIOBSDNameKey);
```

but it is always NULL. So possibly I have to find my `IOMedia *` and call `getProperty()` from there?

Comment: Right ok, so most things I tried failed simply because they are not attached yet. IOBlockStorage does go through a few things, before it decides what to plug in. I still don't know if there is a method called, or a Notification sent, when everything is attached.

But, I found I can call `nub->registerService( kIOServiceSynchronous);` which makes everything be attached before returning. Then a `nub->getBSDName()` can call
        bsdnameosobj = ioregdevice->getProperty(kIOBSDNameKey,
                          gIOServicePlane,
                          kIORegistryIterateRecursively);